# How to confirm the data from Firestore is appended in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the below code to append the data from Firestore in Swift IOS , but when I use "print" function to check whether the data is retrieved or not it doesn't print any actual data
all it prints is the the below kind of details, How should I confirm the data is appended accurately?

CODE

```
var messages: [DocumentSnapshot]! = []

 ref.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
             guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                 print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                 return
             }

            for doc in documents {
              self.messages.append(doc)
              self.clientTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.messages.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                //self.clientTable.reloadData()

            }

print(messages)
```

Print Result

> `Optional([<FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123cbe0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123ccd0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123cd20>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123cd70>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123cdc0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123ce10>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123ce60>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123cf00>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123cf50>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123cfa0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123cff0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123ceb0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d040>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d090>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d0e0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d130>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d180>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d1d0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d220>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d270>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d2c0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d310>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d360>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d3b0>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d400>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d450>, <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x60000123d4a0>])`

Comment: Try using `querySnapshot.data`, I think you should get a `NSDictionary`. Refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the output, the `documents` as [`FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot` objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot), which contain both the data and some metadata about the results.

To get the data from the snapshot, call its [`FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot.data` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot(im)data).

```
var messages: [DocumentSnapshot]! = []

ref.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in

     guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
         print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
         return
     }

    for doc in documents {
      self.messages.append(doc.data())
    }

    print(messages)
}
```

Note that this is also quite well described in the Firebase documentation on [reading all documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection), so I recommend spending some time studying that.